# I have http://localhost:3001/items/product1, how do I add to the filepath to make it http://localhost:3001/items/product1/prices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to add `/prices` to `http://localhost:3001/items/product1/` so I have `http://localhost:3001/items/product1/prices` . I have logic in the items controller for product1 already that I would like to use in /prices as well.

How do I add this route? What is this type of routing called in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html ? I'm getting lost and confused with the amount of routing documentation out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a custom route on the member (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes).

You should be able to do something like that by adding a `get` route nested in the `items` resource

```rb
resource :items do
  get 'price', on: :member
end
```

Here price would be a method on your items controller that would fetch the price page with the relevant data

Comment: Thank you! How would I render /prices as a new page after adding?

Comment: This answer is assuming `product1` is the product id and not the actual string `product1`. 

`/prices` will just be a new method on the `ItemsController`. You will have to create a new view for it under `app/views/items/prices.html.erb`

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new route:

```
match '/items/product1/prices', to: 'controller#action', via: :post
```

or

```
get '/items/product1/prices', to : 'controller#action'
```

To render it as a new page you could `redirect_to 'path'` on a condition met.  That's assuming you are directing multiple routes to one action.  Which you shouldn't do.